# how to create tcl list of multiple list in tcl?

Tags: tcl, itcl

I have list of objects in a variable stored as $m_objs using each object i can get 4 different values like demoRoot demoSuite demoCase and ic so each of those has to be a list of list like this:

```
set data {
    {demoRoot1 demoSuite1 demoCase1 ic1}
    {demoRoot2 demoSuite2 demoCase2 ic2}
    {demoRoot3 demoSuite3 demoCase3 ic3}
    {demoRoot4 demoSuite4 demoCase4 ic4}
    {demoRoot5 demoSuite5 demoCase5 ic5}
    {demoRoot5 demoSuite5 demoCase5 ic5}
}
```

So i tried using foreach loop like this:

```
set tests [list]

foreach ic $m_ics \
{
    set icRoot [$ic getRoot]
    set icSuite [$ic getSuite]
    set icCase [$ic getCase]
    set icName [$ic getName]
    set icList "$icRoot $icSuite $icCase $icName"
    lappend tests $icList
}
```

Output i get is for only one iteration like this

```
puts $icList
PTSE2 actions misc rmon_counters
```

but the Output should be obtained as i mentioned as `set data {...........}`

Please help me to get this one

Comment: The `puts` is only printing the value for one iteration (the last one). The list of lists is built in the `tests` variable; try printing that?

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
set icList "$icRoot $icSuite $icCase $icName"
```

to:

```
set icList [list $icRoot $icSuite $icCase $icName]
```

This will create `icList` as a list rather than a string, and will be appended to the `tests` list as a list.

References: [list](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm)